# How to properly instantiate CIDetector class object in iOS 5 face detection API

Tags: api, ios5

reading the Apple's documentation i tried using it's new face detection API but with no luck,, although there are no compile or runtime errors the instance method ***featuresInImage*** always return an array of CIFeature objects with null values.

First timer on stackoverflow, still tried my best to be short and specific.

Comment: got the correct method from some other source just after posting here :-),, the code is working great,, think i should share it or rather answer my own question :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A minimal code (working) to test out the new iOS 5 face detection API

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0056.JPG"]];

NSLog(@"showing image now");
//[imageView setImage:image];


if (ciImage == nil)
    NSLog(@"CIImage is nil");


//imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:ciImage fromRect:ciImage.extent]];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0056.JPG"]];

NSDictionary *options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"CIDetectorAccuracy", @"CIDetectorAccuracyHigh",nil];
CIDetector *ciDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace 
                                            context:nil
                                            options:options];
NSArray *features = [ciDetector featuresInImage:ciImage];
NSLog(@"no of face detected: %d", [features count]);
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d face(s) detected\n",[features count]];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Face detection" message:myString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
UIImage* uiimage = nil;
CIImage* image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:uiimage.CGImage];
CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]];
```

See here for full tutorial
http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/face-detection-in-ios-5